# Delphi/Paradox Database desktop DBD32.exe settings for Windows 7

Tags: delphi, paradox

Does anyone have any suggestions on the compatibility setting on Windows 7 for the Delphi/Paradox Database desktop program so that it displays properly in Windows 7 (x64)?

We've tried quite a few combinations of selections on the Compatibility tab on the .exe's Properties screen. But, none of them have eliminated fixed our problem:

It runs fine, but the buttons on the structuring screens are missing their text and are not clickable.  The work-around is to use the keyboard shortcuts for these buttons, but obviously, although workable, that's not ideal.

Pre-emptive prose:  Yes, we know we're on risky ground and need to migrate away from Paradox, which in some future version of Windows will not be supported. (But, we've got a million+ lines of code and migration won't be easy...)

Comment: Did you try the "Windows 2000" compatibility setting? Did you install it not in C:\Program Files but in another folder, which have been set to full access for all authenticated users?

Comment: +1 for the pre-emptive part :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm that disabling UAC and moving *Database Desktop* out out `C:\Program Files` makes buttons work again.

**Before:**

[image: Table creation dialog (before)]

**After:**

[image: Table creation dialog (after)]

Answer (score 0):

A few points:

- Try running it with UAC disabled.
- Make sure you have all the BWCC-dlls and stuff in the right places too.
- On Windows XP, check which fonts is uses, make sure those fonts are installed too.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked for me with Delphi 5 Database Desktop on Windows 8, until I realized that I had also installed it through the Delphi 4 setup - and that version of DBD opens fine for me. Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

**so easy answer :
don't use delphi menu to open desktop database but just navigate to this directory
 "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Borland Shared\Database Desktop"
and run  DBD32.EXE
you can also create a shortcut to it on desktop or quick launch on taskbar
i use delphi 7**